# RxJava onErrorResumeNext()

Tags: java, retrofit, rx-java

I have two observables (named A and B for simplicity) and one subscriber. So, the Subscriber subscribes to A and if there's an error on A then B (which is the fallback) kicks in. Now, whenever A hits an error B gets called fine, however A calls onComplete() on the subscriber, so B response never reaches the subscriber even if B execution is successful.

Is this the normal behaviour? I thought onErrorResumeNext() should continue the stream and notify the subscriber once completed as noted in the documentation (https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling-Operators#onerrorresumenext).

This is the overall structure of what I'm doing (omitted several "boring" code):

```
public Observable<ModelA> observeGetAPI(){
    return retrofitAPI.getObservableAPI1()
            .flatMap(observableApi1Response -> {
                ModelA model = new ModelA();

                model.setApi1Response(observableApi1Response);

                return retrofitAPI.getObservableAPI2()
                        .map(observableApi2Response -> {
                            // Blah blah blah...
                            return model;
                        })
                        .onErrorResumeNext(observeGetAPIFallback(model))
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            })
            .onErrorReturn(throwable -> {
                // Blah blah blah...
                return model;
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread());
}

private Observable<ModelA> observeGetAPIFallback(ModelA model){
    return retrofitAPI.getObservableAPI3().map(observableApi3Response -> {
        // Blah blah blah...
        return model;
    }).onErrorReturn(throwable -> {
        // Blah blah blah...
        return model;
    })
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.immediate());
}

Subscription subscription;
subscription = observeGetAPI.subscribe(ModelA -> {
    // IF THERE'S AN ERROR WE NEVER GET B RESPONSE HERE...
}, throwable ->{
    // WE NEVER GET HERE... onErrorResumeNext()
},
() -> { // IN CASE OF AN ERROR WE GET STRAIGHT HERE, MEANWHILE, B GETS EXECUTED }
);
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
Here's a rough timeline of what's happening:

```
---> HTTP GET REQUEST B
<--- HTTP 200 REQUEST B RESPONSE (SUCCESS)

---> HTTP GET REQUEST A
<--- HTTP 200 REQUEST A RESPONSE (FAILURE!)

---> HTTP GET FALLBACK A
** onComplete() called! ---> Subscriber never gets fallback response since onComplete() gets called before time.
<--- HTTP 200 FALLBACK A RESPONSE (SUCCESS)
```

And here's a link to a simple diagram I made which represent's what I want to happen:
[Diagram](http://postimg.org/image/3p0ezxp97/)

Comment: Your timeline shows HTTP 200 for the failure response. Is there some other way you signaling an error from getObservableAPI2()? Also, can you specify which API requests corresponds to the timeline output? It looks like getObservableAPI1->REQUEST B, getObservableAPI2->REQUEST A, getObservableAPI3->FALLBACK A but I just want to make sure.

Comment: Yes, actually although the response is a 200 one, some data may come null, so I throw and error in those scenarios. And yes, that's the timeline-requests relation, I'll edit the question ASAP to match timeline-request as yours.

Comment: Your logic looks sound. You should be getting the fallback response before onComplete. Can you remove all of the subscribeOn() calls and see what happens. They shouldn't be necessary since Retrofit executes the requests on its own thread pool anyway.

Comment: @kjones I already tried that and got the exact same output, onComplete gets called too early.

Comment: It's better to flatten your chain instead of nesting it (makes it super hard to read, trace and debug). It's very unclear what you are trying to do here esp. within the `flatMap` block. Please tidy up your methods and variables, it doesn't matter weather it's Retrofit or not

Answer (score 8):

The Rx calls used in the following should simulate what you are doing with Retrofit.

```
fallbackObservable =
        Observable
                .create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {
                        logger.v("emitting A Fallback");
                        subscriber.onNext("A Fallback");
                        subscriber.onCompleted();
                    }
                })
                .delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .onErrorReturn(new Func1<Throwable, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public String call(Throwable throwable) {
                        logger.v("emitting Fallback Error");
                        return "Fallback Error";
                    }
                })
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.immediate());

stringObservable =
        Observable
                .create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {
                        logger.v("emitting B");
                        subscriber.onNext("B");
                        subscriber.onCompleted();
                    }
                })
                .delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .flatMap(new Func1<String, Observable<String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<String> call(String s) {
                        logger.v("flatMapping B");
                        return Observable
                                .create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<String>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void call(Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {
                                        logger.v("emitting A");
                                        subscriber.onNext("A");
                                        subscriber.onCompleted();
                                    }
                                })
                                .delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                .map(new Func1<String, String>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public String call(String s) {
                                        logger.v("A completes but contains invalid data - throwing error");
                                        throw new NotImplementedException("YUCK!");
                                    }
                                })
                                .onErrorResumeNext(fallbackObservable)
                                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread());
                    }
                })
                .onErrorReturn(new Func1<Throwable, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public String call(Throwable throwable) {
                        logger.v("emitting Return Error");
                        return "Return Error";
                    }
                })
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread());

subscription = stringObservable.subscribe(
        new Action1<String>() {
            @Override
            public void call(String s) {
                logger.v("onNext " + s);
            }
        },
        new Action1<Throwable>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Throwable throwable) {
                logger.v("onError");
            }
        },
        new Action0() {
            @Override
            public void call() {
                logger.v("onCompleted");
            }
        });
```

The output from the log statements is:

```
RxNewThreadScheduler-1 emitting B
RxComputationThreadPool-1 flatMapping B
RxNewThreadScheduler-2 emitting A
RxComputationThreadPool-2 A completes but contains invalid data - throwing error
RxComputationThreadPool-2 emitting A Fallback
RxComputationThreadPool-1 onNext A Fallback
RxComputationThreadPool-1 onCompleted
```

This seems like what you are looking for but maybe I'm missing something.